# Windows phone 7 hebrew support

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, hebrew, right-to-left

I have just downloaded windows phone 7.1 sdk for windows phone 7.5.

I have two problems:
1. When i create a new project I doesn't see the option to choose windows phone 7 or 7.5
2. Windows phone 7.5 should be based on Silver light 4 but when I create label at my application and write hebrew words  it's backwords.

Can I solve the problem at this version?

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the Mango tools, once you select to create a WP7 application you are prompted on a secondary screen to select whether to target 7.0 or 7.1.

Note that the version number of the SDK and tools is 7.1 but phones running Mango are marketed as version 7.5.

Note that WP7[.1|5] does not yet currently provide native support for RTL languages. You may find a workaround at http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/RTL-Arabic-And-Hebrew-Support-For-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone 7 i wrote a mapping function which maps the Arabic encoding[windows-1256] into default WP7 encoding.

```
public static string ConvertToArabic(string s) { short[] mapping = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 8364, 1662, 8218, 402, 8222, 8230, 8224, 8225, 710, 8240, 1657, 8249, 338, 1670, 1688, 1672, 1711, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8211, 8212, 1705, 8482, 1681, 8250, 339, 8204, 8205, 1722, 160, 1548, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 1726, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 1563, 187, 188, 189, 190, 1567, 1729, 1569, 1570, 1571, 1572, 1573, 1574, 1575, 1576, 1577, 1578, 1579, 1580, 1581, 1582, 1583, 1584, 1585, 1586, 1587, 1588, 1589, 1590, 215, 1591, 1592, 1593, 1594, 1600, 1601, 1602, 1603, 224, 1604, 226, 1605, 1606, 1607, 1608, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 1609, 1610, 238, 239, 1611, 1612, 1613, 1614, 244, 1615, 1616, 247, 1617, 249, 1618, 251, 252, 8206, 8207, 1746 };

    string str = string.Empty;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < s.Length; ++ix)
    {
        str = str +  (char)mapping[s[ix]];
    }
    return str;
}
```

This worked for me well.